# Core Data Fetch doesn't return the object it should

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

In Core Data, I have a *Property* entity, with an attribute *currentPage* of type *Integer 16*. It is associated with a class `ATProperty` with a scalar property:

```
@interface ATProperty : NSManagedObject

@property(nonatomic, assign) int16_t currentPage;

@end


@implementation ATProperty

@dynamic currentPage;

@end
```

Now I have the following code to perform a request:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Property"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentPage != 0"];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

Most of the times, it works as intended. But sometimes, I get the following weird results:

```
(lldb)po results
<__NSArrayI 0x17e61300>(

)

(lldb)po [context executeFetchRequest:[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Property"] error:nil]
<_PFArray 0x17e9f3e0>(
<ATProperty: 0x17ec6400> (entity: Property; id: 0x19178e20 <x-coredata:///Property/t88822504-5974-42F5-B8D2-A62325064AFF28> ; data: {
    currentPage = 9;
})
)

(lldb)p (BOOL)[request.predicate evaluateWithObject:0x17ec6400]
(BOOL) $12 = YES
```

So there is one instance of the entity in the managed object context. When I execute my fetch request, Core Data doesn't return this object, it returns an empty array. However, if I test the same predicate on the object that exists in the context, the predicate evaluates to `YES`. Which means the object should have been in the results. How is that possible?

Comment: You pass nil for the error information, indicating that you are not interested in it. Did you ever look at that?

Comment: I didn't because it returned an (empty) array, so there should not be errors. If there was an error, it should have returned `nil` instead of an array.

Comment: What is `performFetchRequest:error:`? That's not a standard Core Data method.

Comment: Sorry I meant `executeFetchRequest:error:`. I wrote from scratch instead of copying/pasting from the actual code and there was no IDE to pinpoint the error (and I still always start to type *perform...* before correcting to *execute...* when I see that autocomplete doesn't kick in).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try your code simulation with below. It's really work for me and also helps us to restrict from crash and other result issues.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"Property"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    NSPredicate *pred =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"currentPage != 0"];

    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSManagedObject *matches = nil;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

    if ([objects count] > 0) {
        NSLog();
    }
```

Hope it helps. Please let me know if we have to go with another solution.

Comment: That's functionally identical to the original code. How is this supposed to help when it's not even different? And what's the point of using `NSLog()` with no string to print?